# Creating an exothermic reaction through exposure to oxygen

Tags: thermodynamics

Is there a way to create a label that when ripped or torn, it's triggered by oxygen and creates an exothermic reaction that heats the object it's surrounding? Say just like a cold cup of coffee or something?

Answer (score 1):

There are products like this already on the market.  A product called Hand Warmers are gloves that make use of exothermic reaction to warm your hands.  And there are cold packs (that make use of endothermic reactions) to put on sports injuries.

Comment: A common hand-warmer,  as @Chester Miller mentioned, contains iron filings (with some salt, water and sawdust, which act catalytically) which oxidize ("rust") so rapidly that the packet gets hot.